# Detect mobile carrier by IP address

Tags: mobile, operator-keyword, carrier

I need to determine mobile carrier name by IP address. I've searched the stack & Google for this, but haven't found anything still working.

My case:

IP 37.108.abc.xyz was used in Poland by carrier Orange. Orange belongs to PTK Centertel which you'll see in ISP name & Domain name by doing the whois. Now, I need to match these. What is more, I need data up-to-date (recently in Poland Era changed to T-Mobile, I want to know that) and lastly, I need API to fetch this data. Of course, I'm willing to pay for such service.

Is there such service? If not, how may I do this on my own?

Comment: I dont really know if that will be working, (so I am not posting an answer) but you should  try this website:   http://www.ipchecking.com/            it gives a lot of information.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, simple WhoIs won't do the job in this case.